# Write permissions to ActiveX on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, activex

I have a software (web interface) from a Chinese manufacturer of security cameras that employs an ActiveX to manage the various functionalities. In particular there is a way to exctract some part of the recordings in the current filesystem of the client computer.

The problem is that the ActiveX seems to not have write permissions on the filesystem (even if no errors are given) and to get actually the video files saved on the client computer I need to run Internet Explorer as administrator.

Is there a less brute way to achieve this? How do I give write permissions to the ActiveX tool?

Comment: I assume this is related to Protected Mode in IE - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462(v=vs.85).aspx#wpm_fliwl